# Why the navbar gets auto right margin while i make it responsive in React and Tailwind CSS?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, tailwind-css, navbar

I'm making a responsive website but due to navbar responsiveness issue i'm facing problem. Why the toggle menu alignment is wrong ? i tried to fix it but it didn't work. See the screenshot here

[image]

So i want to remove this space to make it responsive. I've attached my `navbar` code.

**Navbar.jsx:**

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("");
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const [scrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
      if (scrollTop > 100) {
        setScrolled(true);
      } else {
        setScrolled(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav
      className={`
        ${styles.paddingX} w-full flex items-center py-1 fixed top-0 z-20
        ${scrolled ? "bg-nav-gradient" : "bg-transparent"}
      `}
    >
      <div className="w-full flex flex-1 justify-between items-center max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <Link
          to="/"
          className="flex items-center gap-2"
          onClick={() => {
            setActive("");
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          }}
        >
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="w-9 h-9 object-contain" />
          <p className="text-[20px] font-bold cursor-pointer flex">
            Purnendu Bikash Jana &nbsp;
          </p>
        </Link>

        <ul className="list-none hidden sm:flex flex-row gap-10">
          {navLinks.map((nav) => (
            <li
              key={nav.id}
              className={`hover:text-white text-[15px] font-medium cursor-pointer`}
              onClick={() => setActive(nav.title)}
            >
              <a href={`#${nav.id}`}>{nav.title}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>

        <div className="sm:hidden flex flex-1 mr-0 justify-end items-center text-white">
          <img
            src={toggle ? close : menu}
            alt="menu"
            className="w-[28px] h-[28px] object-contain mx-auto"
            onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
          />

          <div
            className={`${
              !toggle ? "hidden" : "flex"
            } p-5 black-gradient absolute top-20 right-0 mx-4 my-2 min-w-[140px] z-10 rounded-xl`}
          >
            <ul className="list-none flex justify-end items-start flex-1 flex-col gap-4">
              {navLinks.map((nav) => (
                <li
                  key={nav.id}
                  className={`font-poppins font-medium cursor-pointer text-[16px]
                  ${active === nav.title ? "text-white" : "text-secondary"}`}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setToggle(!toggle);
                    setActive(nav.title);
                  }}
                >
                  <a href={`#${nav.id}`}>{nav.title}</a>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

And i set the toggle on from `1040px` screens.

```
screens: {
    xs: "500px",
    sm: "1040px",
},
```

Now if anything more needed let me know.

I tried justify and alignment property but that didn't work. Justify-arround and m-auto align the toggle menu properly but again the right side navbar space still remain. How to remove to make it properly responsive for mobile devices ?

Comment: Consider providing a more minimal example that reproduces your problem. Currently, there seems to be too many obfuscated parts that make it more challenging to recreate your webpage. For example, all the `import`ed assets and code that has been omitted.